# Excel Script - How to output data to another workbook

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-scripts

I want to make a script which outputs data in an external workbook in the same folder. The idea is to use the external workbook as a database and integrate it to Zapier and various other tools as I don't want to create a new Zap for every worksbook ( we have hundreds). Can't find a way to do that using Office Script (we're using Excel Online).

Here's my current script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Zapier'); //Here's the reference to the output sheet
    const AM = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H13');
    const client = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H14');
    const topupcurrency = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H15');
    const topupwallet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H16');
    const grosstopup = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H23');
    const fee = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H22');
    const grossbudget = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H21');
    const convfee = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H20');
    const netbudget = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange('H18');
  const data = [AM.getText(), client.getText(), topupcurrency.getText(), topupwallet.getText(), grosstopup.getText(), fee.getText(), grossbudget.getText(), convfee.getText(), netbudget.getText()]
    addRow(sheet, data);
    return;
}

function addRow(sheet: ExcelScript.Worksheet, data: (string | number | boolean)[]): void {

    const usedRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
    let startCell: ExcelScript.Range;
    // IF the sheet is empty, then use A1 as starting cell for update
    if (usedRange) {
        startCell = usedRange.getLastRow().getCell(0, 0).getOffsetRange(1, 0);
    } else {
        startCell = sheet.getRange('A1');
    }
    console.log(startCell.getAddress());
    const targetRange = startCell.getResizedRange(0, data.length - 1);
    targetRange.setValues([data]);
    return;
}
```

Tried to find a reference but only suggestions were to use Power Automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do it directly using Office Scripts, whoever told you to use PowerAutomate is correct.

This confirms it ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/combine-worksheets-into-single-workbook

Ultimately, if you want to run it over 100’s of sheets, you need to make the script as generic as you can and then return a set of data that you can then pass to the central workbook.

Comment: Can you provide a basic script to actually do that? Collect the new rows in a sheet named Zapier in all the workbooks in the current folder and add them as a new row in a separate workbook

Comment: Technically, I've answered your question.  Sorry but unless you're going to pay OR come back with another question that has a specific issue with a script you've developed, I'm not going to build it for you.  The link I've given you shows the way.

Comment: I prefer paying to be honest because this is way beyond my skill level at this point. Can you help me out and how can we do it?

Comment: I answered a question like this previously. You can see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70488761/16864869

Comment: @Bnikushev does Brian’s answer get you over the line?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I need to build one of the two scenarios and can't find a way so far:

1. Call a flow when user clicks a button in an excel sheet through a script and send the values to a connector or create them in a new row in another workbook. I can set up Zapier to watch for new rows there and trigger the rest of the flow (send the info to Asana and Slack). From what I understand calling a flow through a script isn't supported so far.

2. A script that crawls all the workbooks in a folder, gets all new rows in a certain sheet and writes them down in another sheet.

Comment: The second one is very much possible. PA can detect changes to an excel file, from there, you can pick up the table(s) and sync the data with another workbook. It takes some orchestration but very much possible. Calling a flow with a button isn’t impossible, you can call REST API’s via Office Scripts.