# How to perform VLOOKUP using Office Scripts across multiple workbooks in Excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup, office-scripts

I have two workbooks in Excel: "Job_Salary" and "Deduction_Sheet". In the "Job Salary" workbook, I have a list of employees with their salaries. In the "Deduction_Sheet" workbook, I want to insert each employee's salary from the "Job_Salary" workbook using Office Scripts.

Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to achieve this using Office Scripts? I'd appreciate any help or insights. Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share your sample data in Markdown table instead of image. It is useful for users to test the code and help you.

Comment: It’s not like Excel desktop, you can’t reference another workbook. You need to use PowerAutomate to either 1) combine the workbooks into one or 2) do your lookup on workbook 1 and statically reference the result in workbook 2. This may help you … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70463127/copy-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-in-excel-online/70488761#70488761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** Office Scipts is different with VBA. It can NOT handle multiple workbooks within a script. You may need PA if you can't consolidate two worksheets in a workbook.

*PA1_GetSalary (Office Script)*

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): string {
    // Get work sheet
    let salarySht = workbook.getWorksheet("Job Salary");
    // Get table
    let salaryTab = salarySht.getTables()[0].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    // Load data
    let salaryValue = salaryTab.getTexts();
    let salaryJSON = JSON.stringify(salaryValue);
    return salaryJSON;
}
```

*PA2_SetSalary (Office Script)*

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, strJSON: string) {
    // Get work sheet
    let deductionSht = workbook.getWorksheet("deduction");
    // Get table
    let deductionTab = deductionSht.getTables()[0].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    let deductionValue = deductionTab.getTexts();
    // Store the empployee - salary list with Map object
    let salaryValue: string[][] = JSON.parse(strJSON);
    let myMap = new Map<string, string>();
    for (let i = 0; i < salaryValue.length; i++) {
        myMap.set(salaryValue[i][0], salaryValue[i][3]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < deductionValue.length; i++) {
        if (myMap.has(deductionValue[i][0])) {
            deductionValue[i][4] = myMap.get(deductionValue[i][0])
        }
    }
    // Update table
    deductionTab.setValues(deductionValue);
}
```

*Power Automate flow*

[image]

---

*Below code only works for two worksheets in a workbook.*

Option 1: Load data into array and loop up the value

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get work sheet
    let salarySht = workbook.getWorksheet("Job Salary");
    let deductionSht = workbook.getWorksheet("deduction");
    // Get table
    let salaryTab = salarySht.getTables()[0].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    let deductionTab = deductionSht.getTables()[0].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
    // Load data
    let salaryValue = salaryTab.getValues();
    let deductionValue = deductionTab.getValues();
    // Get the salary value
    for (let i = 0; i < deductionValue.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < salaryValue.length; j++) {
            if (deductionValue[i][0] === salaryValue[j][0]){
                deductionValue[i][4] = salaryValue[i][3]
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Update table
    deductionTab.setValues(deductionValue);
}
```

When dealing with a large dataset, utilizing a `Map` object can significantly improve lookup efficiency.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get work sheet
  let salarySht = workbook.getWorksheet("Job Salary");
  let deductionSht = workbook.getWorksheet("deduction");
  // Get table
  let salaryTab = salarySht.getTables()[0].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  let deductionTab = deductionSht.getTables()[0].getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  // Load data
  let salaryValue = salaryTab.getTexts();
  let deductionValue = deductionTab.getTexts();
  // Store the empployee - salary list with Map object
  let myMap = new Map<string, string>();
  for (let i = 0; i < salaryValue.length; i++) {
    myMap.set(salaryValue[i][0], salaryValue[i][3]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < deductionValue.length; i++) {
    if (myMap.has(deductionValue[i][0])) {
      deductionValue[i][4] = myMap.get(deductionValue[i][0])
    }
  }
  // Update table
  deductionTab.setValues(deductionValue);
}
```

---

Option 2: Retrieve the salary value using the XLOOKUP (or VLOOKUP) formula and then convert the formula into a static value. The formula dynamically captures the data range using table column references within the formula.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get work sheet
    let salarySht = workbook.getWorksheet("Job Salary");
    let deductionSht = workbook.getWorksheet("deduction");
    // Get table
    let salaryTab = salarySht.getTables()[0];
    // XLOOKUP formula
    let formulaLU = "=XLOOKUP([@Employee],Table1[Employee],Table1[Annual Salary])"
    let deductionTab = deductionSht.getTables()[0];
    // Update formula with (salary) table name 
    formulaLU = formulaLU.replace(/Table1/g, salaryTab.getName());
    let dataCol = deductionTab.getColumnByName("Annual Salary").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal()
    // Set formula
    dataCol.setFormulaLocal(formulaLU);
    // formula to value
    dataCol.setValues(dataCol.getValues());
}
```

Comment: “Two workbooks” not WORKSHEETS, it’s not possible to do what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I'll add a note for that.

Comment: But you *can* create VLOOKUP formulas in a script that reference other workbooks. You just can't reference other workbooks from the script itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLOOKUP by setting a cell's formula, then get the value. This script should get the salary values corresponding to the employee IDs in the Job Salary workbook.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  const range = workbook.getWorksheet("Deduction).getRange("E2:E15");
  range.setFormula("=VLOOKUP(A2, '[Job Salary.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$E$15, 4)");
  console.log(range.getValues());
}
```

Comment: “Two workbooks” not WORKSHEETS, it’s not possible to do what the OP wants.

Comment: I tested this on two workbooks earlier. Does this not work for you?

Comment: @AlexanderJerabek thanks for the answer and its worked for me also. Is there any possibility to use it in a dynamic range?

Comment: This should work anywhere Excel would automatically adjust the relative range references. You could have the script programmatically create the range references. I'll confess this is where my knowledge of Scripts outpaces my Excel knowledge....